# Get Yii user state variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I am using `Yii::app()->user->setState` to set some user's session variables.

Is there a way to get the values of them from within JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps? You have to echo it to the JavaScript.

```
<script>
var myVariable = "<?= Yii::app()->user->getState('myVariable', '') ?>";
alert(myVariable);
</script>
```

Comment: It's the only way for now. I thought may be there is a better solution, but it seems there isn't.